# How does Azure eventhubs specify rowkey and partitionkey?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-eventhub

I have inherited an application set where the C# .Net application sends an event to Azure EventHubs, which then sends the data from that event to Azure Table Storage. There is a very computed RowKey being set, and a selected column of the message is the Partition Key. I now want to change these things, and cannot find where it is specified. The .Net code, of course, only has to create a Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.EventData which has a PartitionKey column, but that is not set by the code.

I have studied the EventHub itself, thinking there might be a transformation or formula configured into it, but I don't see anything there either.

Thanks

Comment: Is "storage blob container" you mention so different from "Azure Table Storage"? I see in the event hub in Azure as configured in my C# app. And I see data in the table storage that correlates to what was sent to the Event Hub. There must be some mechanism here, and i don't see any other apps in our repo that could be involved in it.

Comment: Thanks! I just stumbled on the same concept Googling around. The Stream Analytics job is doing the transformation into the PartitionKeyAlias and RowKeyAlias columns. I presume I can just change how those compute, to get what I need. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

> I have inherited an application set where the C# .Net application sends an event to Azure EventHubs, **which then sends the data from that event to Azure Table Storage.**

An event hub does not send anything, it only receives things (apart from [the ability to store all messages to an azure storage blob container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-overview)). So there is another process in play that forwards the events to the table storage.

I advice to take a look at the azure subscription the event hub belongs to. Maybe there is an azure function or stream analytics job that reads the event hub. Those can be build using the azure portal only so you would not see an app in your repo.